# Optimize SQL query with multiple SELECT's

Tags: mysql, optimization, count

The following SQL query slows down my website **extremely** much! From 0-1.5 seconds to easily over 20 seconds. How can I optimize it?

```
SELECT DATE(a.datetime_logged) AS date,
(SELECT COUNT(aa.data_status) FROM activity AS aa WHERE aa.id_user = '1' AND DATE(aa.datetime_logged) != CURDATE() AND DATE(a.datetime_logged) = DATE(aa.datetime_logged) AND aa.data_status = 'online') AS status_a,
(SELECT COUNT(aa.data_status) FROM activity AS aa WHERE aa.id_user = '1' AND DATE(aa.datetime_logged) != CURDATE() AND DATE(a.datetime_logged) = DATE(aa.datetime_logged) AND aa.data_status = 'idle') AS status_i,
(SELECT COUNT(aa.data_status) FROM activity AS aa WHERE aa.id_user = '1' AND DATE(aa.datetime_logged) != CURDATE() AND DATE(a.datetime_logged) = DATE(aa.datetime_logged) AND aa.data_status = 'streaming') AS status_s

FROM activity AS a
GROUP BY DATE(a.datetime_logged)
ORDER BY DATE(a.datetime_logged) DESC
LIMIT 40
```

Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `activity` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_channel` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `id_game` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_muted_server` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_muted_self` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_deafen_server` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_deafen_self` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_suppressed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `data_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `data_game` text,
  `datetime_logged` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `index_datelog` (`datetime_logged`)
)
```

Comment: Is your query correct? Are you sure you dont want to include the part of subquery where clause predicate in your main query where clause? Can you describe what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have never used multiple SELECT's so I don't know, really. After some Googling and an answer from here, this was the result.

Comment: So, you can describe your goal using some wording. Try to update your question.

Comment: No need. Dennis Cheung solved it for me.

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key, so toss the unique key.

Comment: Consider changing to `data_status ENUM('online', 'idle', 'streaming') NOT NULL`.  (Add more options if needed.)

Comment: @RickJames: I want to have different aliases(?) like `status_a` and `status_i`. With `data_status ENUM(...` it is not possible? Many thanks for the primary key and unique key comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `sum(case data_status when 'online' then 1 end) as status_a` to replace nested heavy sub-queries

Comment: Oh. Wow! I didn't know that. Many thanks for your answer! I will accept it when I can :)

Comment: Shorter:  `SUM(data_status = 'online')` -- because a boolean is treated as 0(false) or 1(true).

Comment: Very nice solution, Rick James :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have subqueries of this form:

```
SELECT COUNT(aa.data_status)
  FROM activity AS aa
 WHERE aa.id_user = '1'
  AND DATE(aa.datetime_logged) != CURDATE()
  AND DATE(a.datetime_logged) = DATE(aa.datetime_logged)
  AND aa.data_status = 'online'
```

These are nasty, especially if the cardinality of your `id_user` and `data_status` columns is low.  The `DATE(aa.datetime_logged) != CURDATE()` term makes these queries non-sargable.

Try a compound index on `(id_user, data_status, datetime_logged)`. It might help a bit.

You could also try

```
SELECT COUNT(aa.data_status)
  FROM activity AS aa
 WHERE aa.id_user = '1'
  AND aa.datetime_logged >= DATE(aa.datetime_logged)
  AND aa.datetime_logged <  DATE(aa.datetime_logged) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND DATE(aa.datetime_logged) != CURDATE()
  AND aa.data_status = 'online'
```

with the same compound index.  That would allow an index scan.